# Can't set Dart SDK in Android studio

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio-3.0

Linux Mint 20.1

In my Flutter project.

I install Dart

https://dart.dev/get-dart

So the Dart location is here on my machine:

```
whereis dart
dart: /usr/bin/dart /usr/lib/dart
```

Nice.

Now I want to set this path in Android Studio.
[image]

As you can see I get error that **Dart SDK not exist**

Answer (score 1):

Dart SDK with Flutter provided in `flutter/bin` directory. In your case, if you provide a valid Flutter SDK path to Flutter plugin, Android Studio automatically detects Dart SDK. If you want to set Dart SDK directly, use it from `flutter/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

## update 2024

The dart is available in the `drive:\path\to\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk` folder. moreover you need to set the module that dart is enabled

For example, in my case since I installed my flutter sdk inside the `E:\.cache\flutter\` therefore the dart path would be `E:\.cache\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk`

moreover don't forget to set which module include dart file, otherwise dart sdk won't be enable for those folders

[image: image of android studio setting page, configuring dart sdk folder]